# python convert ipv6 to an integer

Tags: python, ipv6

Is there any package or easy way to convert an ipv6 to an integer? The algorithm should be a little smart to understand the ipv6 short formats. Before I start to write my own code , I just wonder if anyone knows a package that can do the job?

Thanks,

Comment: @stark: Python supports arbitrary-length integers.

Comment: Its not as if you can do much with such an integer, it would be interesting to learn of the use cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with some help from the **standard** Python socket module. [`socket.inet_pton()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton) handles IPV6 short form without any trouble.

```
import socket
from binascii import hexlify

def IPV6_to_int(ipv6_addr):
    return int(hexlify(socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ipv6_addr)), 16)

>>> IPV6_to_int('fe80:0000:0000:0000:021b:77ff:fbd6:7860')
338288524927261089654170743795120240736L
>>> IPV6_to_int('fe80::021b:77ff:fbd6:7860')
338288524927261089654170743795120240736L
```

Comment: you could use [`struct.unpack()` and simple arithmetic to get the integer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895244/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: sure, that works too, but using hexlify() and int() seems much clearer to me. It is obvious that you are converting a base 16 string to an int etc. Conversely, using struct.unpack() with its esoteric format string (which I always have to look up) and then fiddling the bits is not as clear, IMO.

Comment: There's also `'foo'.encode('hex')`, which saves you from having to remember where hexlify lives.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution using only stdlib:

```
import socket
import struct

def int_from_ipv6(addr):
    hi, lo = struct.unpack('!QQ', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, addr))
    return (hi << 64) | lo
```

#### Example

```
>>> int_from_ipv6('fe80::fbd6:7860')
338288524927261089654018896845572831328L
```

On Python 3.3+ you could use [`ipaddress` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html):

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> int(ipaddress.ip_address('fe80::fbd6:7860'))
338288524927261089654018896845572831328
```

Answer (score 7):

You want [IPy](http://c0re.23.nu/c0de/IPy/).

```
>>> IPy.IP('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860')
IP('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860')
>>> IPy.IP('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860').int()
338288524927261089654170743795120240736L

>>> IPy.IP('fe80::fbd6:7860')
IP('fe80::fbd6:7860')
>>> IPy.IP('fe80::fbd6:7860').int()
338288524927261089654018896845572831328L
```

Comment: See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/ and https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy

Answer (score 4):

Using [`ipaddr`](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) module

```
>>> import ipaddr
>>> int(ipaddr.IPAddress('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860'))
338288524927261089654170743795120240736L
```

Edit: thanks to @J.F.Sebastian for better way

Comment: you could use [`socket.inet_pton()` to get packed representation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895244/4279).

Comment: if you choose to use `ipaddr` module then you could `int(ipaddr.IPAddress('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860'))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, There was a similar question a few days ago. That's how I did it then :) Someone said ipaddr was getting into the std lib so I thought I'd use it here

Comment: the module *based* on `ipaddr` is added as `ipaddress` module in Python 3.3+ on a provisional basis.

Answer (score 1):

May be `netaddr` you want.

```
>>> from netaddr import *
ip = IPNetwork('fe80::21b:77ff:fbd6:7860')
>>> print ip.value
338288524927261089654170743795120240736
```